# Image and Button as same height using LinearLayout?

Tags: image, button, height

I am using LinearLayout with weightSum so I can design generic screen to run on all screen sizes. Maybe I couldn't understand wrap_content and match_parent attributes properly.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
          tools:context="com.hbss.hybridsoftwaresolutions.rashidfaheem.mysecondapplication.easypercentagecalculator.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="#0d001c"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </View>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5"
    >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/image01"

    />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Percent Calculator"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/btnPCalculator"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </View>


</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image04"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Percent Increase"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/btnPIncrease"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </View>


</LinearLayout>







    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image05"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Percent Decrease"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/btnPDecrease"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </View>
</LinearLayout>








    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image02"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tip Calculator"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/btnTCalculator"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </View>
</LinearLayout>






        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="5"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image03"

                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Percent Margin"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:id="@+id/btnPMargin"
                />
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            </View>

    </LinearLayout>





    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image06"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Percentage Change"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/btnPChange"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </View>
        </LinearLayout>




    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/image07"

            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Percentage (what % of)"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:id="@+id/btnPWhatof"
            />
        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </View>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be your ImageView and Button heights. Try to set them to match_parent instead of wrap_content:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/image01"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Percent Calculator"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/btnPCalculator"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

You should use match_parent so both TextView and Button heights fill all the space available within your LinearLayout. If you use wrap_content, they'll take only the space they need ignoring the rest of the space available.

Comment: When i use match_parent for image and button, they take whole screen space. Actually i am using two linear layouts. First one with vertical orientation which fill 7 lines of blocks (image+button) vertically and in that vertical laylout every line of block (image+button) has its own horizontal linear layout which adjust image+button+empty space(View) with their weight.

Comment: Ok. I edited my post and pasted whole xml code. What should i do to make images and buttons with equal heights?